# SQL Server 2008 return 0 when no row is found

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wonder if anyone can assist me?

I currently writing a performance management report from stats data within our database

I am trying to count the number of jobs each member of staff completes on a monthly basis however, some months staff won't complete any so there will be no entry for that month.

Currently I have written:

```
SELECT
  CAST(MONTH(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + 
                               CAST(YEAR(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Month,
  s.staff,
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN COUNT (*) 
    ELSE 0 
  END AS Jobs,
  ot.monthly_target AS Target
FROM tb_statistics AS s
LEFT JOIN tb_staff_targets as ot ON (s.staff = ot.staff)
GROUP BY s.staff, 
         CAST(MONTH(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' 
                                      + CAST(YEAR(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(4)),
         ot.monthly_target
```

Now the counting is working fine for data over 0 but where one member of staff has added a job for say, April then I want the other staffs to display 0 until they add data etc

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you provide a sqlfiddle of your problem?

Comment: Sqlfiddle isn't building the schema for me at the moment. Not liking the statistics table part...

Answer (score 0):

When I read your question this comes to mind:

- Get the sum of jobs done, grouped by month and employee
- Get a list of months in which jobs are done
- Get a list of employees
- Do a full outer join to combine months with employees
- Do a left join of the combinations with the calculated sum of jobs done
- Use coalesce to replace the NULL values by zero

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that all the staff you want are in the table `tb_staff_targets`, then you want to switch the order of your join, from a `left join` to a `right join`:

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + 
                               CAST(YEAR(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Month,
       s.staff,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN COUNT (*) 
             ELSE 0 
        END) AS Jobs,
      ot.monthly_target AS Target
FROM tb_statistics s RIGHT JOIN
     tb_staff_targets ot
     ON (s.staff = ot.staff)
GROUP BY s.staff, 
         CAST(MONTH(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' 
                                      + CAST(YEAR(s.Date_Entered) AS VARCHAR(4)),
         ot.monthly_target
```

This will keep everything in the staff table (all the staff) along with their statistics.

If the staff are not in this table, then you need some source for the list of staff that would be given a value of `0`.